# How can i improve stereo calibration accuracy?

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d, emgucv

I want to calibrate stereo camera in c#(in Emgu library). but the calibration accuracy is very bad[this is an example of disparity map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OxbK.png)!Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: Why do you think it's bad?

Comment: Because the disparity map is very noisy!

Comment: Can you tell the rectified image pair is good enough? For example, a point in the 3D is mapped to the points in the rectified images at the same Y position? If you are not sure, please show your rectified images of, for example, the checker board image.

Comment: @hiroki
Dear  Hiroki,
Thank you for your response. I have attached an example of disparity map. As you see in the attached picture, disparity map is very noisy, could you please how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the two corner positions are not aligned vertically in the right and left images (red lines). Thus the stereo matching would fail. (Your disparity image is not noisy - it is just invalid.)

I think there is a problem producing the rectified images but I have no clue unless you provide more information on how you made the images.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the stereo vision algorithm must be able to delete this misalignment. In the attached file [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USoIS.png), rectification images are shown. It seems the rectified images are good, but disparity map is very bad. What is your idea?
Thank you